# Why are “Gonna Find Out” hats already being awarded?

Tags: support, winter-bash, winter-bash-2018

The description for the [‘Gonna Find Out’](https://winterbash2018.stackexchange.com/gonna-find-out) hat is:

> cast 150 votes on questions or answers

I've come across a few users with “Gonna Find Out” hats. Since Winter Bash has only been on for 3 days and there is a limit of 40 votes on questions and answers per day, how is this possible?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Votes on posts which are subsequently deleted **do not count** towards your daily limit of 40 votes, but they do towards the Gonna Find Out hat, just like with e.g. the Electorate badge.

According to [an official source](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/48057996#48057996), this is the correct answer.

It's [not the case that close, reopen, delete and undelete votes count as well](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/48057946#48057946), it's just up- and downvotes.

Comment: Seems like your theory's correct, https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/48057996#48057996 :)

Answer (score 14):

I got mine at about 00:10 UTC on the second day of Winter Bash. The first day I went on a rampage on Stack Overflow and flagged / downvoted a lot of non-answers and low quality posts and managed to rack up 130 votes for the day. As Glorfindel mentioned you get the votes back once a post is deleted and if I'd been a bit more determined I could have probably got 150 in the single day.

Also anything voted on between 00:00 and 03:00 UTC that gets deleted by the Roomba refunds the votes placed against them one they're deleted so it's not unusual for someone to be able to vote a lot more than 40 times per day.