# Why did my vote go through even after I reached the daily maximum amount of votes?

Tags: support, voting, voting-limits

I just tried to down-vote a question. It gave me this message as usual:

[image: Daily vote limit reached; vote again in 15 hours.]

But my vote still went through. I refreshed the page, and the down-vote I cast still showed. I refreshed multiple times, and it was still visible. Is this a bug or something?

This shouldn't happen, as I've reached the daily maximum already.

Should I be worried? Is this a bug?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks like you just cast the last vote for the day; you see the same message when you reach the vote limit as when you actually try to cross over the limit.

> No.. that can't be my last vote, i had that message already before.

One or more of the posts you voted on has been deleted; that frees up the votes you used there. In this way, it's possible to cast more than 40 votes a day; that's why [people were getting Gonna Find Out hats on the third day of Winter Bash already](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/320134/295232) even though it requires 150 votes. Your [profile page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zOk5C.png) even shows you have cast 42 votes, which means (at least) 2 of them must have been on deleted posts.

Comment: No.. that can't be my last vote, i had that message already before.

Comment: Still impossible: i went on my activity tab and: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zOk5C.png

Comment: Why do you think it shows 42 votes?

Comment: Am.. cuz i managed to vote after daily limit...

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/users/current?tab=votes&sort=upvote and https://stackoverflow.com/users/current?tab=votes&sort=downvote; votes on deleted posts won't appear there.

Comment: True, got it, you're amazing...

Answer (score 4):

When you see the blue "daily vote limit reached" box, that means the vote you just cast was your last one for the day. The red box, however, means you already used up all your votes *before* the one you just tried to cast.

If you saw the blue "daily vote limit reached" dialog already that day, but you're able to cast another vote, it means one of the posts you cast a vote on was deleted.

Answer (score 3):

This is the message that you get when you have *just reached* the maximum number of votes. You won't be able to cast any votes *after* this on - it's a bit confusing, as it gives the same message for both when you run into the limit and when you've passed the limit.

If you go look at the "votes" tab in your profile, you'll probably find 40 votes there - not 41.

So [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign), not a [bug](/questions/tagged/bug).

Or, as @Glorfindel [notes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/320682/294691) after your comment, it could be that one of the posts that you had voted on was deleted. After that happens, you can re-use that vote.

Comment: Impossible: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zOk5C.png

Comment: @U9-Forward that count includes votes on deleted posts

Comment: See here for someone getting 70 votes in one day: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/239868/130540