# Was this question auto-deleted (roomba'ed) while being a duplicate?

Tags: support, duplicate-questions, deleted-questions, community-user

I *thought* duplicates with no answers aren't deleted, but if negative score they're deleted. This was confirmed by [this example](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/89284):

> [image: roomba'ed]

But the FAQ led me [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/roomba) which says otherwise, namely it checks:

> not closed as a duplicate

... before deleting.

So was something changed, something different applies here, or something went wrong?

Comment: The "not closed as a duplicate" only applies to that one criterion (RemoveAbandonedClosed) and not to other criteria: see [Can (and should) duplicate questions be automatically deleted?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/328351/can-and-should-duplicate-questions-be-automatically-deleted). If you look at the timeline, you'll likely see that it was deleted per a different criterion (probably RemoveDeadQuestions).

Comment: @Sonic: can I pivot to updating [that help center page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/roomba)?

Comment: I think it's clear as it is. Each criterion has a separate set of bullet points, and the one you quote is only in one of them.

Comment: Does the question's timeline make it any clearer what caused it to be deleted?

Comment: @Robert: it says `RemoveDeadQuestions`. Clearer now after what Sonic said.